# Is Brick Tamland from the future?

Tags: character, anchorman-2

In Anchorman 2, Brick Tamland alludes to the future and his knowledge of it multiple times. For example, he tells the news crew how they will all be flying around on jetpacks ten years in the future. Also, in the battle scene,

> Brick has a gun from the future, and does not tell Ron or the news team where he got it from.

Is Brick from the future?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brick doesn't appear to be *from* the future, but is a character who (like [Brian Fantana](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H_GMMD_GCTg), [Champ Kind](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuHezFweJ40) and Veronica Corningstone) is able to use [direct address](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=jUNzWOMQz2EC&pg=PA156&lpg=PA156&dq=direct%20address%20introduction%20of%20characters%20in%20film&source=bl&ots=NYpdLmiESb&sig=jvUOszRkb6N7KDoSfQy8u6tTxtk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eJ1bU-ipGMmrO_yQgdAP&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=direct%20address%20introduction%20of%20characters%20in%20film&f=false) to the audience, as such breaking the fourth wall.

This can be evidence withing the first film, where the characters introduce themselves to camera; although Corningstone only uses direct address in voiceover, and then only once.

This is supposed to be inferred [as a cinematic technique](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ObdvAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT38&lpg=PT38&dq=direct%20address%20introduction%20of%20characters%20in%20film&source=bl&ots=cq3fKfKcya&sig=YdhlxXyonVoHmcJYo30d_O3VUyo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=eJ1bU-ipGMmrO_yQgdAP&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=direct%20address%20introduction%20of%20characters%20in%20film&f=false) rather than something actually occuring within the film, in what is known as an 'extradiegetic element'.

Anchorman's natural playfulness with form and content means it is able to very humoursously play with the conventions of cinema, and largely abandon concerns towards continutity: Hence Brick's acquisition of a 'Lazer Gun' amongst other preposterously implausible plot developments.

They are playing with form deliberately to find humour, its not supposed to be a sub-plot or additional element.

That being said, Brick is also the only character who is able to reveal his foreknowledge of the future in the first Movie, [during his introduction:](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=19X3VHY3qZs)

> I'm Brick Tamland. People seem to like me because I am polite and I am
>   rarely late. I like to eat ice cream and I really enjoy a nice pair of
>   slacks. **Years later,** a doctor will tell me that I have an I.Q. of
>   48 and am what some people call mentally retarded.

It's possible to infer from that this Brick is capable of precogniction, but its much more likely that this is just a technique employed for humour and not deliberate sub plot.

After all: it's funny that we don't know (and neither does he!) where Brick got his 'Future-Gun'; If it was an established subplot that he was a time traveller, this wouldn't work as a joke.

Comment: Ah didn't even think of the first movie quote. I do see what you mean with the playing with the script (as it is anchorman) but I don't understand how Brick being from the future wouldn't be a joke...

Comment: The joke works because it's so obsurd that Brick would have such a weapon, and no explanatation is given. If his acquisition of the weapon was explained and detailed, there would be no humour. The entire point of the joke is the absurdity of it.